# How to hide association table results in a linked query with sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I associate 2 tables `A` and `B` with table `AB`:

`A.belongsToMany(B, {through: AB})
B.belongsToMany(A, {through: AB})`

The problem is, when I doing some queries:

`A.getBs();
B.findOne({
    ...
    include;[{model:A}]
})`

There always be some extra results about association table:

`AB.a; AB.b;
AB:{
  a,
  b,
}`

How can I exclude these?

Answer (score 11):

Solved by myself, with many tries > <

```
through:{
    attributes: []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

usually it works with

```
through: {
    attributes: []
}
```

but u can also try this one

```
 joinTableAttributes: []
```